# How to draw polyline by percent value(like 30%) in google maps javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I want to draw polyline using some percentage value, like I want to draw 30% of polyline only.
How can I achieve this in google maps javascript ?

Comment: What does your code look like that currently draws the polyline?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get 2px wide polyline.
        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({path: flightPlanCoordinates,geodesic: true,strokeColor: '#FF0000',strokeOpacity: 1.0,strokeWeight: 2
        });
      flightPath.setMap(map);

Answer (score 0):

It basically depends on the Lat Lng values you provide to draw a line. You will get only half of the poly line. So incase you want 30% of the poly line, calculate the 30% of the lat long values and provide them to flightPlanCoordinates. It will show until that.
Hope this helps!